# Strange output iterating va_list varibles

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I want to write a function whose task is printing only nonnegative components of input vector.

So, my first attempt is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <math.h>
#define BIG_INT 100
void print_nonnegatives(int arg1, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, arg1);
    for (int i = arg1; -BIG_INT < i && i < BIG_INT; i = va_arg(ap, int))
    {
        if (i >= 0)
        {
            printf("%d ", i);
        }
    }
    va_end(ap);
    puts("\n");
}

int main()
{
    print_nonnegatives(1, 3, -4, 5, 6);
    print_nonnegatives(-1);
    print_nonnegatives(7, -1, -1, 9);
}
```

It works; but there are some dirty lines. For example, if one of the arguments is bigger than BIG_INT, it will fail.

I tried to change the condition -BIG_INT < i && i < BIG_INT to escape from this failure. So, I replaced it by i / i == 1. My main problem is that what are strange outputs and from where they are coming from?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <math.h>
#define BIG_INT 100
void print_nonnegatives(int arg1, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, arg1);
    for (int i = arg1; i / i == 1; i = va_arg(ap, int))
    {
        if (i >= 0)
        {
            printf("%d ", i);
        }
    }
    va_end(ap);
    puts("\n");
}

int main()
{
    print_nonnegatives(1, 3, -4, 5, 6);
    //print_nonnegatives(-1);
    //print_nonnegatives(7, -1, -1, 9);
}
```

Comment: You cannot do this (at least not in C). You need to provide either with a sentinel value that terminates the list, or provide the number of arguments for example in the first argument.

Comment: Since you added C++ as a tag, you could use variadic arguments instead. (If you are not in interested in a C++ answer, then remove the C++ tag!)

Comment: `i/i == 1` is `true` (except when `i` is zero, when it's undefined (so the compiler will probably optimise it to `true`)). Why did you think that would ever exit the loop?

Comment: So please explain in your *own words* when the `for` loop is supposed to end given those conditions...

Comment: As Jabberwocky said - you must use first argument as number of items that you pass to the function. IT must be first argument since when 'cdecl' calling convention is used, the first argument has known and fixed location in stack frame so 'callee' can use it to determine how much stuff was pushed on stack as arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "bad output" comes from the fact that you don't pass an argument to end the argument list.

The `va_arg` function won't automatically return some kind of "end of argument list" value when you reach the end of the argument list, instead it will just give you the "next" argument in infinity. That means you will go beyond the end of the argument list and have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to pass a value larger or smaller than `BIG_INT` to end the argument list (with the first example shown).

Comment: **undefined behavior**. That is the key. Great thanks for mentioning this keyword. 
I repaired my code by replacing `#define BIG_INT 100` with `#define BIG_INT    21474836 // temporarily true
#define SMALL_INT -21474836 // temporarily true` and so `-BIG_INT < i && i < BIG_INT` with `SMALL_INT < i && i < BIG_INT`. And no need to control the statement by number of arguments. Let me hope DMR come back to the world and write a third edition of K&R.

Answer (score 0):

You must tell your function how many ints you pass to it - first argument can tell that. BTW - it must be first argument since when 'cdecl' calling convention is used, the first argument has known and fixed location in stack frame so 'callee' can use it to determine how much stuff was pushed on stack as arguments. You may do it like so:

```
#include <cstdarg>
#include <iostream>

void print(int howMany, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, howMany);

    while(howMany--)
    {
        int nextNum = va_arg(args, int);
        if (nextNum > 0) std::cout << nextNum << std::endl;
    }

    va_end(args);
}


int main()
{
    print(9 /*tells how many ints follows*/, 10,-20,30,40,-50,60,-70,80,90);
}
```